# Android App is pretty unstable on background service to scan AltBeacons

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

i am working on AltBeacons development and i had some problemas with wifi adapter. When the AltBeacon scan is running the wifi internet dont work, so i cant request info from internet when an AltBeacon was detected. I did tried it on: Moto G, Moto X and Sony Xperia SP.and Sony Xperia z1,Sony Xperia z and Samsung sm(core-2) , xolo q1100

Another problem is when the scan is running on Android background, i need run this scan all the time to detect new AltBeacons? That make the application pretty unstable, maybe because it uses a lot of phone process and memory. Somebody have any information or case about AltBeacons Scan on Android background mode?

Thanks!